# how to downloads a file that is located under asset folder

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do you properly download a file that is located under static folder ?

I know using html, you can use something like `<a href="static/image/phoenix.png" download> click here to download file </a>` but in Elixir it doesnt working, instead it is downloading a file named `phoenix.png` but that file can not be opened, the browser says **Failed - No file**

I have tried using something like `<%= link "click here", to: "./image/phoenix.png" %>` but it still not working. I'm getting `no route found for GET /image/phoenix.png (MyTestsWeb.Router)`

Here is my git repository where I put my example: https://github.com/zairecrypto/test.git

can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo? `image/phoenix.png` -> `/images/phoenix.png`.

Comment: still doesnt work, I am still getting `no route found for GET /phoenix.png (MyTestsWeb.Router)`

Comment: Are you sure? I've downloaded your repo and changing this line in the controller fixed it: `file = "/images/phoenix.png"`.